# Disable default Content Provider during testing

Tags: android, testing, android-contentprovider

I have a custom `ContentProvider` that picks off objects from a static `LinkedBlockingQueue` member inside my custom `ContentProvider` class. The static queue is loaded with objects from within another class.

Now the problem I have is during `ContentProvider` testing when the system creates a mocked instance of the `ContentProvider`. That is all fine, but the problem I have is that the default production-code `ContentProvider` is still alive during testing. Since both the default and the mocked `ContentProvider` are instances of the same class they share the same static `LinkedBlockingQueue`. What happens in my tests then is that the default `ContentProvider` is alive and "steals" the objects in the queue from my mocked `ContentProvider` operating on the same static queue. Thus, what I need is a way to disable the default `ContentProvider`. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this during the test phase only?

In short:
How can I disable the ordinary `ContentProvider` while testing with a mocked `ContentProvider`?